# Alterar tamanho de texto de lis não funciona

Tags: css, css3

Tenho o site abaixo:

http://funerariasaopedro.net.br/novo/

Nele tem um `slider`, no inicio da página. Nesse `slider` tenho uma `imagem` (logo) e uma `ul` (que contem algumas atividades).

O que ocorre é que quando reduzo o tamanho do navegador (resolução da tela), tudo acompanha. Mas o tamanho da imagem e da `ul` não reduz embora o tamanho do `slide` show reduza.

Sim, fiz o @media query.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width:1023px) {
    .cycle-slideshow .logo-atividades .logo{
        width:10% !important;
    }
    .cycle-slideshow .logo-atividades .atividades ul li a {
    font-size: .1rem !important;
    font-weight : auto  !important;
    line-height : auto !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: Carlos editei minha resposta e acho que resolvi sei problema, depois olha na resposta os detalhes e testa ai

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Edit

Os problemas dos espaços sobrando a direita do site eu corrigi fazendo um `overflow-x:hidden` no html e body, e depois colocando `box-sizing:border-box` nos elementos coma a class `.aos-item` para o padding deles não interferirem no layout.

```
html, body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
.aos-item {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height: 300px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

---

Pelo que eu vi esses CSS deve resolver o problema do alinhamento e do tamanho da logo.

OBS: Vc vai ter que fazer outras variações de media quary `@media` para tratar a altura da UL em algumas larguras de tela `.cycle-slideshow .logo-atividades .atividades` *Deixe a observação no código abaixo.*

```
.cycle-slideshow .logo-atividades {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    max-width: 500px;
    height: 305px;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 999;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.cycle-slideshow .logo-atividades .atividades {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%; /* aqui vc controla a altura da UL de acordo com a largura da tela*/
    width: 100%;
    height: 115px;
    overflow: hidden;
    pointer-events: none;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 10;
    color: #FFF;
}
```

**Agora sobre o espaço que vai sobrando do lado direito é devido a esse JS que vc usou nas suas `<sections>`, tanto que depois que vc colocar esse CSS acima e remover as `sections` vc vai ver que o bug some**

Esse elementos com a classe AOS que vem entrando da direita e esquerda `data-aos="fade-right"` acredito que estejam bugando a largura da tela e dando o epaso branco no topo, retire eles e o bug some tb...